# Parsing an underscore delimited string of fields using regex or most efficient method in Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

My title might be a little misleading.  I can easily parse the string manually but I am looking for the FASTEST way to detect specific values in 2 specific fields.  So given an example string of:

XXX_X_999999_999999_99999999_99999999_X_X where x = alpha, 9 is numeric, I want to confirm the values (which are dates) in fields 5 and 6 are one of a couple specific years.

So in field 5 it might be 20100101, I want to see if year matches one of several years.  Same for field 6, but different years.  It could be two different expressions I guess?

I looked at some solutions using regex to scan for values in a comma delimited file but altering the check did not seem to work as I expected it would using underscores (instead of focusing on a specific field it seemed to look at the entire string).

Again, I can do this by splitting the string, then checking those two fields, but I was hoping to do something faster, simply verifying on the fly (analyzing a number of these strings at a whack) if specific values are in the right place in the string.

example:

XXX_X_100000_200000_20100101_20100130_X_X

I want to match the first date (field 5) with the year 2001 and 2002.

[edit]

I should note that I am terrible with regular expressions, the one I tried to modify for my purposes was: ^([^,\r\n]*,){5}(2001|2002)

Comment: Provide examples rather than `Xs and 9s`

Comment: I'm not convinced a regex would be faster than a simple split and check, but maybe it is. If the string is always in the same format it doesn't seem like the regex would be that tricky--perhaps this would be a good opportunity to learn one of the more useful tools at a programmer's disposal?

Comment: Just how many of these strings are you verifying at each whack?

Comment: Updated the title...  provided better example of data.

Comment: It depends but it can range from 10 to 1000 or more at time and page rendering times will be affected by the quantity.

Comment: if the string is fixed length - then just substring the date parts out by position.

Comment: @DaveNewton I always thought that using regex pattern analysis (done properly) would be quicker than parsing strings using string libraries?  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Randy Field lengths for the fields leading up to the dates can vary by one or two characters.  As it is now I simply split based on the underscores and analyze the individual values, but I want to be able simply loop through them, apply the pattern and verify if a value is there... but if you guys think it might not be quicker to use regex then I will drop the idea.

Comment: @Tuishimi That depends on the regex, obviously. Not much will be faster than Randy's "substring" suggestion. You'd need to time the options to know which would be faster.

Comment: @DaveNewton Alright!  Then I will stick with the way I am doing it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overuse regular expressions for everything.

**There is nothing wrong with splitting the string** and parsing it traditionally.

You can of course also use e.g. `(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)` to have the regular expression pre-split dates into YMD for you. Nevertheless, if something is supposed to be a number, process it as number, not as string.